# Stop make if find -exec returns not zero

Tags: bash, makefile, find

I'm trying to integrate checking my code using `pyflakes` into a building process. I've defined the following target in my `Makefile`:

```
pyflakes:
    find $(APPLICATION_DIRECTORY) -iname "*.py" -exec pyflakes "{}" \;
```

The problem is that `find` returns `0` every time even if there are code issues (`pyflakes` returns not `0`) and `make` succeeds. Ideally, I want to run the check on every source file and stop `make` if at least one of `-exec` failed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume there is no way to make `find` return exit code of `-exec`.
What should work is piping to `xargs`:

```
find $(APPLICATION_DIRECTORY) -iname "*.py" |xargs -I file pyflakes file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just pipe the output of find to your own processing loop and exit when pyflakes returns an exit status other than 0.

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' | \
while read line ; do
    pyflakes "$line"
    res=$?
    if [ $res -ne 0 ] ; then
        exit $res
    fi
done
```

Comment: `cmd; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then foo; fi` is just an antipattern; the proper way to code that is `if cmd; then foo; fi` or simply `cmd || foo`.

Comment: I do not see any improvement.  The edit you want is `pyflakes "$line" || exit $?`, short and simple.

Comment: i don't see any advantage to your way. the point is that it's shorter?

Comment: The main thing is that it is unidiomatic to explicitly examine `$?` in most circumstances; the function of `if` is to run a command and check if its exit code is zero or not.

Answer (score 1):

Make it end the find process by

```
pyflakes:
    find $(APPLICATION_DIRECTORY) -iname "*.py" -exec bash -c 'pyflakes {}; if [[ $$? != 0 ]]; then kill -INT $$PPID;fi' \;
```

This is what goes into the makefile, it is not a script file, if you wonder about the syntax.

Comment: It is enough to write `-exec bash -c 'pyflakes {} || kill $PPID' \;`. For me this works a bit slower than the `-quit` predicate, tested with: `find -name '*.cpp' \( -print -a -exec g++ -c {} \; -o -quit \)`.